# Do I recommend specific training?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

In my answer to [Resources for communicating & dealing with "hot buttons" as a software developer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/46956/resources-for-communicating-dealing-with-hot-buttons-as-a-software-developer) I suggest the OP follows some trainings to help him distinguish his own 'red buttons'.

I know of one training course ([The Landmark Forum](http://www.landmarkworldwide.com/the-landmark-forum)) that specifically addresses that, and since pariticipating in it, that helps me quickly distinguish them with myself. Should I add that specific recommendation to my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the specific course helped you and is something that is broadly available (i.e. something that readers might be able to follow up on), then it sounds like adding it would enhance your answer.  When making a specific recommendation it's a good idea to say something about how it helped you (not just "here's a link") so people can tell you're not spamming.  And, of course, if it's something you're affiliated with you must disclose that.  (I don't think that's the case for you here, but I'm writing this answer more broadly.)

Comment: Thanks. Added recommendation to the answer.